# python Error : must be char not unicode

Tags: python-2.7

```
def get_point_id(point_type, id):#id is str,like："001"，“1001.0”
    if not id:
        return None
    if True:
        str_id = str(int(id))
        if point_type == 'alarm':
            return str_id.rjust(3,'0')# error
```

When I run it ,the console display:

> File "b2_insert_standard_template_signals.py", line 118, in get_point_id
>
> > return str_id.rjust(3,'0') 
> >     TypeError: must be char, not unicode

str_id is a str,not unicode,I don't know why. This py file already declare   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my python version is 2.7.3. Please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/captin411/ofxclient/issues/21

Comment: @rai_zhang Ran your code in python 2.7.12. Works fine. No errors. Can you show how are you calling the `get_point_id` method?

Comment: I just want to format the id . like this： value=get_point_id(point_type, id),  filnal ，the vale will be stored a dict's value

Answer (score 0):

ok，I know what happened. because I declare “ # -- coding: utf-8 --” in the front of the .py file.
so  the second argument of the rjust method is utf-8 encoding. This is wrong. 
the second argument of the rjust method must be "str".

It's  funny